# Array syntax in Java: what is the significance of the [] location

Tags: java, semantics, arrays

```
String S[] = new String[3];
String[] S = new String[3];
```

Both ways are proper in Java. Does it mean that for every type `Type[] x` is the same as `Type x[]`?

Comment: I think that this would more properly be called "*Syntax* in Java", but it really isn't a big deal...

Comment: Please close before 100 "Yes they are the same" answers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The difference is if you declare multiple variables on the same line:

```
String A[], B, C;
```

would result in A being an array of Strings, whereas B and C are Strings.

```
String[] A, B, C;
```

would result in A, B and C all being arrays of Strings.

Comment: We have a winner, good thinking

Answer (score 3):

yes both are same.
but

`String[] s;` is more readable because If you have thousand line of code some time

you may read `String s[]` like `String s`;

but in `String[] s` you will read as proper String array.

---

Also if you declare multiple varialbes in one line

like `String[] x,y,z;`

and `String x[],y,z;` you can read the difference easily.

Answer (score 3):

*Well as we already have many answers I just want to add something*

```
//Valid declarations
String[]array;//With No Space
String[] a;
String []b;//<-----
String c[];
String[] d,e,f;
String g[],h[],i[];
String[] []y;
String[] []z[];
String []p[];
etc.
```

---

```
String v[],[]w;<----Not Allowed
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's exactly the same. You can write `public static void main(String[] args)` or `public static void main(String args[])` for your main method (or anything else of course). It's a good idea to standardize on whichever makes more sense to you (most likely `String[]`). The choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

yes both are same. The second one makes more sense as it reads `A String array s` directly.

Comment: Well, you *could* say "`s` is a `String array`", which makes sense, while "`s array` is a `String` (huh?)", but that really is a contrived example and in the end it still comes down to personal preference, and in the end you'll still use `s` by itself...